# React router dom redirect function is not redirecting

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I have a `fetch` function in my `useEffect` that gets some data from the backend, but it sends a JWT token to check for user authorization to retrieve the data.

In case the user is not authorized I want to redirect it to my unauthorized page, but the `redirect` function just does not work at all, it does absolutely nothing at all.

This is what my `useEffect` looks like:

```js
useEffect(() => {
  const populateData = async () => {
    const response = await OS_Service.getAll('user.token');

    if (!response) return redirect('/unauthorized')
      
    setAllServiceOrders(response.data);
    setFetching(false);
  };
  populateData();
}, [setAllServiceOrders, user]);
```

Anyone knows why it is not working?

Comment: Do you have any guards in '/unauthorized' route?

Comment: The issue might be with the redirect function that you're trying to call inside the useEffect hook. Can you provide more information on how you've implemented the redirect function? Also, make sure that the redirect function has the necessary logic to redirect the user to the desired page.

Answer (score 0):

```
import { useHistory } from 'react-router-dom

const Comp = () =>{
const history = useHistory()
 ......
    useEffect(() => {
        const populateData = async () => {
          const response = await OS_Service.getAll('user.token');

          if(!response) history.push('/unauthorized')
  
          setAllServiceOrders(response.data);
          setFetching(false);
         };
        populateData();
      }, [setAllServiceOrders, user]);
  ........
  return (<>......</>)
}
```

Comment: I went for a try catch with a useNavigate to move to the unauthorized page, the redirect function was just refusing to work for some weird reason

Answer (score 0):

The [`redirect`](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/fetch/redirect) utility function is for use only in `Route` loaders and actions. In React components you should use the `useNavigate` hook.

Example:

```js
const navigate = useNavigate();

useEffect(() => {
  const populateData = async () => {
    const response = await OS_Service.getAll('user.token');

    if (!response) {
      navigate('/unauthorized', { replace: true });
      return;
    }
  
    setAllServiceOrders(response.data);
    setFetching(false);
   };

  populateData();
}, [setAllServiceOrders, user]);
```